# postgre: перенести значение поля в другое поле для дубликатов

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с полями: num, name, num2. Есть дубли с разными num, но одинаковыми name. Нужно записям, у которых num больше 10 в поле num2 прописать num их дублей.

```
create table table3 (num integer, name varchar(100), num2 integer);
        insert into table3 (num, name) values ('1', 'арбуз');
        insert into table3 (num, name) values ('4', 'мандарин');
        insert into table3 (num, name) values ('5', 'киви');
        insert into table3 (num, name) values ('10', 'банан');
        insert into table3 (num, name) values ('14', 'мандарин');
        insert into table3 (num, name) values ('28', 'арбуз');
        select * from table3;
```

Таблица до

<kbd>`num`</kbd>  <kbd>`name`</kbd>    <kbd>`num2`</kbd> 
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`арбуз`</kbd>       
<kbd>`4`</kbd>    <kbd>`мандарин`</kbd>    
<kbd>`5`</kbd>    <kbd>`киви`</kbd>        
<kbd>`10`</kbd>   <kbd>`банан`</kbd>       
<kbd>`14`</kbd>   <kbd>`мандарин`</kbd>    
<kbd>`28`</kbd>   <kbd>`арбуз`</kbd>

Таблица после

<kbd>`num`</kbd>  <kbd>`name`</kbd>    <kbd>`num2`</kbd> 
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`арбуз`</kbd>       
<kbd>`4`</kbd>    <kbd>`мандарин`</kbd>    
<kbd>`5`</kbd>    <kbd>`киви`</kbd>        
<kbd>`10`</kbd>   <kbd>`банан`</kbd>       
<kbd>`14`</kbd>   <kbd>`мандарин`</kbd><kbd>`4`</kbd>   
<kbd>`28`</kbd>   <kbd>`арбуз`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>

Comment: Картинки - в мусор. Данные выкладывайте форматированным текстом. Ещё лучше - прямо сразу форматированным кодом, CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: *Нужно записям, у которых num больше 10 в поле num2 прописать num их дублей.* Две копии таблицы - одна обновляется, вторая поставляет данные для обновления. PS. Если некоему `name` соответствует две записи с разным `num` менее 10 (скажем, 2 записи для яблока с `num=2` и `num=3` ), то какая из них должна использоваться для обновления?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Akina есть только 2 записи для каждого значения name и одно всегда с кодом до 10, а дублирующая запись с кодом после 10, т.е. таких случаев "Если некоему name соответствует две записи с разным num менее 10..." - нет

Comment: Подтвердите это - выложите CREATE TABLE таблицы с обеспечивающим это constraint.

Answer (score 0):

В приложении к моей задаче вопрос решен. Может, кому понадобится.

```
WITH ttt AS (
  SELECT name, 
        min(num) as num
  FROM table3 GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name)>1
)
UPDATE table3
  SET num2 = (SELECT num FROM ttt WHERE ttt.name=table3.name )
WHERE table3.num > 10
```